# Redux-form actions dispatch one-by-one not from form component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'm creating a form with redux-form and pagination related to the results the form produces. Both form and pagination are separate components and pagination is located outside the form component.

My idea is when a click to pagination occurs redux-form's action creators are dispatched one-by-one - first fires `change()` action that changes `page` field in the form and then fires `submit()` action that submits the form.

Everything works almost fine except one thing: something works weird even though pagination click handler passes correct page number, but `submit()` occurs with **previously** clicked page number. I'm stuck and can't figure out what's wrong, 'cos when I wrap `submit()` into `setTimeout()` everything works fine.

Here are links to github:

- [dispatch change() and submit() in form component](https://github.com/LazzyLizzard/elCat/blob/f0f316c6d35dc26327584fd22f53d904f9a24be0/src/pages/pick/pick-list/pick-list.jsx#L66)
- [pagination component and click handler](https://github.com/LazzyLizzard/elCat/blob/f0f316c6d35dc26327584fd22f53d904f9a24be0/src/components/ui/pagination/pagination.jsx#L30)

I know that my code leaves much to be improved and keep in mind that almost all data is mocked and backend is not complete too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without looking too close, it sounds like such an issue could be caused by the index starting from 0 rather than 1. I encountered an issue like this when building pagination, when activePage was 1 but firstPage was 0. Check to see if that could be the case.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not the root of the problem :-(

`pagination: {
        current: 1,
        total: 20,
        items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }`

Comment: dispatch doesn't block, so the dispatch(submit) doesn't wait for the dispatch(change) to complete, so it will use whatever is in the state before the change function is executed.  you might be looking for this: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1676.  checkout redux-saga ;)